# Icon doesn't change to the new one

Tags: android, android-studio

I've replaced all my old icons with new. Did a gradlew clean build and still the old icons are displayed?

Can someone help me with this?

Working in latest Android studio

Comment: have you  deleted your old icons from all drawable folder??

Comment: Yes I did and then did everything AndroidWarrior told me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try clicking on synchronize for all drawable folders ? Right click on drawable-hdpi,-xhdpi etc and click on synchronize

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Android Studio helped me

Answer (score -1):

1. Delete the **gen** and **bin** folder from your project
2. Clean and build the project
3. Run the project

Comment: You mean just delete the build folder?

Comment: @user1007522 No i mean, in your Package explorer in eclipse you can see multiple folders like src, assets,libs,res etc... There select **gen** and **bin** folder and delete them and follow the steps i told

Comment: Yes but I don't have a bin and gen folder there. Only a build folder with an apk folder..

Comment: @user1007522 How did you replace the icons if you only have an apk with you and haven't imported the project in your Android studio?

Comment: I've tested now on Samsung G s 2 and it works. I need to restart my htc one I think. So many days uptime probably messed up.